# diff function in Live Editor

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to use Live Editor in Matlab to do some symbolic calculus operations. I get some problems with the `diff` function.

I am simply trying to define a few variables which are to be stacked into a vector and a matrix. Then I calculate the quadratic form of the just defined vector and matrix. Finally, I want to differentiate the quadratic form with respect to the first variable of the vector used to calculate it.

This is my test code:

```
syms a b A B C D T P
V =[a b]
M = [A B ; C D]
T = V*M*V.'
P = diff(V* M *V.',a)
```

I would expect the derivative of `T` with respect to `a`.
I obtain this error:

> Error using symfun/subsref (line 172)
>   Symbolic function expected 1 input arguments but received 2.

Comment: The symbolic toolbox in MATLAB has the nasty property of sometimes working on 'old' definitions on your variables (try, for example: `syms a positive; clear a; syms a; assumptions(a)`). Try and restart MATLAB, and if that does not work, post a minimum working example (MWE) that gives the error on a freshly started MATLAB session.

Comment: (or, perhaps, try `reset(symengine)`)

Comment: Thanks Sanchises.
Resetting the symengine seems to have fixed the problem!